# check syntax errors on mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, syntax

I have an issue to check syntax error on MySQL dump file. Please inform me a tool or command to check syntax on MySQL dump file.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

A "mysql dump file" *created by mysqldump* should not contain any errors.

You might hit problems if you're trying to port data into an *earlier* version of MySql; the dump file might use [newer] syntax that the older version cannot understand.

An *example* of the problem would be useful.

You could always try mysql itself.  Try loading the file into a new database and see what fails.

Comment: Another source of error may be the difference in encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually safest to use the `mysqldump` associated with the *target* version of MySQL.

The way to "test" the syntax is to actually load the data using `mysql ... < dumpfile`.  But, do that on a separate version of MySQL from anything you don't want clobbered.